# How to stop rotating an image which is taken by iPad?

Tags: html, windows, image, ipad, rotation

I take several photos using iPad. I take them in different orientations (rotate iPad every time on 90 degrees).
Then I download them to my Windows laptop and what I see? I don't see them as I saw them on the screen of iPad. Actually, there is only one valid image. Others are rotated.

I found this problem in browser (FF & Chrome). When you display image using img html tag it is rotated. But if you display it by entering image's full URL - it's totally OK.

I checked pictures via Safari on iPad - they look fine (in img tag), but don't in Windows.

Is there some metadata which shows that image should be rotated or smth like this?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the iPad has a hardware device in it that tells it the device orientation, which is how it determines how to display the screen to the user. While the hardware instantly knows how it's positioned at any given time, they seem to have engineered a lag into the software registering this change to improve the user experience (so the screen doesn't flip back and forth several times in a single second). However, this lag might lead to some unexpected results when taking a photo.

I have found that the orientation is most often unexpected with the iPhone / iPad when I am taking photos with my screen facing downward (i.e. taking a picture of something on a tabletop, for example). I assume landscape but get portrait, and vice versa. In that scenario (downward / flat), it is more difficult for the device to know what my  intended orientation is.

I find the best way to resolve this is to hold the device in the clear orientation that I want for a second before I take the photo, then point the camera downward and snap.

The orientation data is included in an image's metadata (AKA exif data). You can take a look here for more information:

http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/

It is relatively easy to retrieve (and modify) the exif data in software. If you are doing lots of batch processing in some type of custom way, libraries are available to help with this for a variety of frameworks. But for small jobs, the absolute most simple way is to click the little "rotate" icon in the image viewer software within Windows which will make the update for you.

Comment: And one other thing... Some programs ignore / don't use the exif orientation tag which is why you'll see images display properly in one program and not in another.